# How to remove liveData forever observe in viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Using liveData in viewModel, I observe if any web api response return, but how to remove specific observe with removeObserve method?

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun buttomSubmit() {
        val responseLiveData = webFetch()
        responseLiveData.observeForever(
            Observe {  // define a Observe?
                doSomething()
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        responseLiveData.removeObserver(observer)  // how to correctly remove the observe
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: no point in calling removeObserver inside onCleared() because this function will get called only on destroy of fragment/activity.

Comment: You shouldn't use LiveData for single callbacks, you should use a callback.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your observer and store it

```
val mObserver: Observer<MyClass> = Observer { obj ->
    doSomething(obj)
}
```

then you can start observing forever with

```
responseLiveData.observeForever(mObserver)
```

and then stop

```
responseLiveData.removeObserver(mObserver)
```